# 404s and Sitecore login redirect to a different site in the Sitecore instance

Tags: multisite, site-configuration

Having an odd problem with a production instance. When I enter a page that doesn't exist, such as `www.mysite.com/asdijdsiajdi`, the typical Sitecore "Document Not Found" page appears, however the subdomain changes to `campaigns.mysite.com` (which is a different site in the `<sites>` node from our main one). Additionally, logging into Sitecore via `www.mysite.com/sitecore` redirects to `campaigns.mysite.com/sitecore/login?returnUrl=%2Fsitecore%2Fshell`. It's definitely not a global redirect on the `www.mysite.com` domain, as going directly to that URL does not redirect to `campaigns.mysite.com`; instead, it seems like any Sitecore pages or operations are handled through this Campaigns site.

Below is my current `<sites>` node (extracted from `showconfig.aspx`), although I've replaced the true domain with `mysite` as I've done above. As you can see, `BHCorporate` is the site that represents `mysite.com` and `BH-campaigns` represents the campaigns URL.

```
<sites>
  <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableTracking="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="15MB" viewStateCacheSize="1MB" xslCacheSize="25MB" disableBrowserCaching="true" contentLanguage="en" patch:source="Sitecore.Speak.ItemWebApi.config" enableItemLanguageFallback="false" enableFieldLanguageFallback="false" itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity" itemwebapi.access="ReadWrite" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"/>
  <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableTracking="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" language="en" patch:source="Sitecore.DefaultLanguage.config"/>
  <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx"/>
  <site name="service" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service"/>
  <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true"/>
  <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true"/>
  <site name="dummy" virtualFolder="/sitecore/content" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/doesnt exist" startItem=""/>
  <site name="BhCentersSite" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="false" hostName="centersite.mysite.com" targetHostName="centersite.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Centers" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BH-enroll" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="enroll.mysite.com" targetHostName="enroll.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Enroll" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BH-appreciation" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="appreciation.mysite.com" targetHostName="appreciation.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Appreciation" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BhEmployers" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="true" hostName="solutionsatwork.mysite.com" targetHostName="solutionsatwork.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/SAW" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" notFoundItem="/sitecore/content/SAW/Home/page-not-found" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BhSchools" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="true" hostName="schools.mysite.com" targetHostName="schools.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Schools" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BhSchoolsPreview" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="preview-schools.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Schools" startItem="/home" database="master" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="0MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="0MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="false" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BhBuca" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="true" hostName="backupcenters.mysite.com" targetHostName="backupcenters.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/BUCA" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BhEdAssist" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="true" language="en" hostName="www.edassist.com|edassist.com|tuitionadvisory.net|www.tuitionadvisory.net" targetHostName="edassist.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/EdAssist" startItem="/home" database="web" notFoundItem="/sitecore/content/EdAssist/Home/page-not-found" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BhJobs" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="false" language="en" hostName="jobs.mysite.com" targetHostName="jobs.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Jobs" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BhBucaPreview" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="preview-buca.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Buca" startItem="/home" database="master" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="0MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="0MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="false" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BH-campaigns" virtualFolder="/" language="en" checkOldCampaignTrackerRedirects="true" checkRedirects="true" physicalFolder="/" hostName="campaigns.mysite.com" targetHostName="campaigns.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Campaigns" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"/>
  <site name="BH-clients" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="true" checkCampaignTrackerRedirects="true" hostName="clients.mysite.com|www.clients.mysite.com" targetHostName="www.clients.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Client Microsites" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true"/>
  <site name="BhCentersNew" targetHostName="child-care-preschool.mysite.com" settingsItem="{AD4AD16F-0301-4A98-927C-9507BD912C24}" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="true" hostName="child-care-preschool.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Centers New" startItem="Center List Page" database="web" domain="extranet" port="443" externalPort="80" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" scheme="https" patch:source="mysite.Website.Project.config"/>
  <site name="BhCentersNewPreview" targetHostName="preview-child-care-preschool.mysite.com" settingsItem="{AD4AD16F-0301-4A98-927C-9507BD912C24}" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="true" hostName="preview-child-care-preschool.mysite.com" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Centers New" startItem="Center List Page" database="master" domain="extranet" port="443" externalPort="80" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableTracking="true" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" scheme="https" patch:source="mysite.Website.Project.config"/>
  <site name="BHCorporate" hostname="bhcorporate|corp.bhdts.com|mysite.com|www.mysite.com" language="en" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Corporate-New" startItem="/home" database="web" cacheHtml="false" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" checkRedirects="true" checkCampaignTrackerRedirects="true" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" patch:source="mysite.Feature.Corporate.config"/>
  <site name="scheduler" enableTracking="false" domain="sitecore"/>
  <site name="system" enableTracking="false" domain="sitecore"/>
  <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true"/>
  <!--
 ITEM WEB API SETTINGS FOR A SITE
           Supported attributes (first is default):
             itemwebapi.mode: [Off|StandardSecurity|AdvancedSecurity]
               If set to Off, Item Web API is turned off.
               If set to StandardSecurity, Item Web API is turned on. Default Sitecore security model is used.
               If set to AdvancedSecurity, Item Web API is turned on. Default Sitecore security model is extended with a requirement to explicitely set the 'remote:fieldread' access right for content fields.
             itemwebapi.access: [ReadOnly|ReadWrite]
               If set to ReadOnly, then only READ operation is allowed.
               If set to ReadWrite, then CREATE, READ, UPDATE, and DELETE operations are allowed.
             itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess: [false|true].
               Defines if access is allowed for non-authenticated user.

-->
  <site name="website" language="en" patch:source="Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config" itemwebapi.mode="Off" itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" enableItemLanguageFallback="false" enableFieldLanguageFallback="false"/>
</sites>
```

I have `Preview.DefaultSite` set to `BHCorporate`, in case it matters. Otherwise, I can't seem to see why the campaigns site is being redirected to for any and all Sitecore stuff. Any idea on what could be causing this? Are there any other config settings I can check? We are using Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161115.

Comment: Hi Paul, were you able to find any solution to this issue?

Comment: @SurbhiKochhar unfortunately, no